# What I can do to find fastly superimpositions?

Tags: qgis, vector, vector-layer

I have a project with several geometries belonging to several vectors (more than 10)...
I need to locate the areas where there is a superimposition between two geometries not necessarily belonging to the same vector...

How I can do this operation? I am using QGis 2.12.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TopologyChecker plugin to check for overlap between geometries in one or more layers.

Open the TopologyChecker plugin and click the wrench to configure the rules. To find areas where LayerA overlaps with LayerB, add this rule:

```
LayerA must not overlap with LayerB
```

To find overlapping features in LayerA, add this rule:

```
LayerA must not overlap
```

Add as many rules as you need, click OK, then click the check mark to Validate All. Areas of overlap will be highlighted in red.